# Getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM and while run the app it crashes at  `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` line and gives below error :

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help me for solve this issue?

Comment: Could you add your app level gradle file to your question and the version of the device's Google Play services? This looks like an issue with the version of the SDK vs the version of Google Play services installed on the device.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the API in Google project console ,and also create the keys which required for FCM from your project console.
Also try to Uninstall your app once and check,because onTokenRefresh() will call once,

Please follow the below link for more information.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Please check below once --

> Use Google Play services 9.0.0
>
> Android Studio 1.5 or higher
>
> An Android Studio project and its package name.

Comment: Android Studio : 2.1.2 &
Google Play services 9.2.1

Comment: what is the 'Google Play Services' to Revision ?

Comment: also try to downgrade the play service version,and give a try,if its work i can update the answer with proper fix
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'   try this

Comment: Still it is same issue